# Micronaut Redis Test Resources not working

Tags: testing, redis, micronaut, lettuce

I am not able to get Test Resources (Redis) running in our project.
I am not able to find the problem in a couple of days. I started a new minimal project to identifier and isolate the problem, which is the same sadly.

https://github.com/kgreulich/redis-testresources-demo

I read the documentation multiple times and don't know what the problem is.

```
[ERROR] com.example.ServiceTest.testGet -- Time elapsed: 60.03 s <<< ERROR!
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: 
Error instantiating bean of type  [io.lettuce.core.RedisClient]
Message: java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out
Path Taken: DefaultRedisClientFactory.redisClient(AbstractRedisConfiguration config,ClientResources defaultClientResources,List mutators) --> DefaultRedisClientFactory.redisClient([AbstractRedisConfiguration config],ClientResources defaultClientResources,List mutators)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2322)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1328)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.$DefaultRedisClientFactory$RedisClient0$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1756)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1731)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:856)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:346)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.RedisConnectionUtil.findRedisClient(RedisConnectionUtil.java:133)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.RedisConnectionUtil.openBytesRedisConnection(RedisConnectionUtil.java:113)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.cache.RedisCache.<init>(RedisCache.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.cache.$RedisCache$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.instantiate(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:159)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2893)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:3518)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3470)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3440)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:1436)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:95)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBeansOfType(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2253)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeansOfTypeForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1476)
    at io.micronaut.cache.$DefaultCacheManager$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1328)
    at io.micronaut.cache.interceptor.$CacheInterceptor$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2893)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:3518)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3470)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3440)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBeanRegistrations(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBeanRegistrations(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2321)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanRegistrationsForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1500)
    at com.example.$Service$Definition$Intercepted$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1672)
    at com.example.$ServiceTest$Definition.inject(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doInjectAndInitialize(DefaultBeanContext.java:2636)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.inject(DefaultBeanContext.java:1010)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeEach(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:441)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.beforeEach(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:223)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:165)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: io.micronaut.testresources.client.TestResourcesException: java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out
    at io.micronaut.testresources.client.DefaultTestResourcesClient.request(DefaultTestResourcesClient.java:144)
    at io.micronaut.testresources.client.DefaultTestResourcesClient.resolve(DefaultTestResourcesClient.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.testresources.client.TestResourcesClientPropertyExpressionResolver$DelegateResolver.callClient(TestResourcesClientPropertyExpressionResolver.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.testresources.client.TestResourcesClientPropertyExpressionResolver$DelegateResolver.resolve(TestResourcesClientPropertyExpressionResolver.java:98)
    at io.micronaut.testresources.core.LazyTestResourcesExpressionResolver.resolve(LazyTestResourcesExpressionResolver.java:45)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.resolveExpression(DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.java:182)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver$PlaceholderSegment.getValue(DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.java:300)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholdersObject(DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourcePropertyResolver.resolvePlaceHoldersIfNecessary(PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java:799)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourcePropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java:393)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.getProperty(DefaultApplicationContext.java:230)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolvePropertyValue(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2108)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getPropertyValueForSetter(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1076)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.$DefaultRedisConfiguration$Definition.inject(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.$DefaultRedisConfiguration$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:571)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
    at io.micronaut.testresources.client.DefaultTestResourcesClient.request(DefaultTestResourcesClient.java:134)
    ... 160 more
```